# Adding Multiple timestamps, One with Checkbox

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I am looking to add a second timestamp, connected to a checkbox. I currently have it set to put a timestamp in Column D when B is filled in. I would also like a timestamp in Column O when Column A checkbox is checked.

Here is my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h40jXZ-V0fe8oLDSQ2NmbTDW5dk3WKgZJvZ7ROcwChY/edit?usp=sharing

Progress update:

I have figured out the 2 scripts that work separately but am struggling on how to combine them so they work simultaneously.

Script 1:

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Work Order Queue" ) { 
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

Script 2

```
function onEdit() {

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

if( s.getName() == "Work Order Queue" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet

var r = s.getActiveCell();

if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column

var nextCell = r.offset(0, 14);

if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?

nextCell.setValue(new Date());

}

}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested to [ask].

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/112389/88163,  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122968/88163, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/131976/88163, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/138939/88163,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the [timestampMultipleColumns_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/28719648?msgid=28825318) script with these parameters:

```
    // [START modifiable parameters]
    var timestampSettings = [
      {
        sheetsToWatch:       /^(Work Order Queue)$/i,
        columnLabelsToWatch: ['Received by', 'Complete'],
        columnValuesToWatch: [undefined, true],
        columnLabelsToStamp: ['Time Start', 'Phone Call Time'],
        overwriteTimestamps: [false, false],
        eraseTimestamps:     [false, false],
        columnLabelRow:      2,
        timestampFormat:     'M/d/yy H:mm am/pm',
      },
    ];
    // [END modifiable parameters]
```

The script lets you insert timestamps in an arbitrary number of columns in an arbitrary number of sheets.